# mirror effect in javafx

Tags: javafx, mirror, pane

I need to display a `Button` in a `javafx.scene.layout.Pane` extending class object which comes from a given API.

I manage to put the buttons where I want but they're displayed with a mirror effect like on this [picture](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_Rf56AL-pm3Y/TP-0h5tWr8I/AAAAAAAAIOY/NJjp2jLQy-c/s320/inverted-text-word-2010-6.png).

To fix this, I'm trying to do the opposite effect (is this a good idea?); I already found the 
[`setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation value)`](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Node+Orientation+in+JavaFX) method for Node class but one can only reverse the orientation in a horizontal way (left-to-right --> right-to-left). Does there exists a way to reverse a node vertically? Is there a better way to display my `Node` (a button) normally?

Thanks

Comment: What API are you extending and *are* those buttons expected to be mirrored? Maybe there is a switch in the class you are extending? I'd dig into that direction, before reversing the element myself.

Comment: Why are the buttons displayed in a mirrored effect ? Is the pane rotating the button?

Comment: @user1438038 : the API is Jpedal, I haven't seen a switch but there is a DrawAdditionnalObject in it...  Which doesn't work with javafx yet.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha : the button are basic, just a text in it made by myself. So I think it's the pane that rotates the button.

Answer (score 9):

The Node's method `setScaleY(double scale)` sets the change of scale of the node:

- `1.0` --> 1/1 scale (default)
- `2.0` --> 2/1 scale
- `-1.0` --> 1/1 scale but with a symmetry with respect to the axis on which this value is applied.

So in order to flip a button vertically:

```
myButton.setScaleY(-1);
```

For french people : [Node manipulating](http://java.developpez.com/faq/javafx/?page=Noeuds#Comment-agrandir-ou-retrecir-un-noeud)